# Generate JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, json, spring

I want generate under JSON code in Java:

```
  {
    "rowsPerPage": 10,
    "page": 1,
    "total": 100,      
    "rows": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "name1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "name2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "name3"
            }
        ]
}
```

I know how generate rowsPerPage, page and total, but I don't know how generate rows?

```
            ModelMap modelMap = new ModelMap();
            modelMap.put("rowsPerPage", 10);
            modelMap.put("page", 1);
            modelMap.put("total", 100);
```

Comment: Yes it looks like array, but how do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, you want something like this:

```
ModelMap [] rowMap = new  ModelMap()[3];
for (int i=0;i<3;i++)
{
  ModelMap this_row=new ModelMap();
  this_row.put("id",i);
  this_row.put("name","name"+i);
  rowMap(i)=this_row;
}
modelMap.put("rows",rowMap);
```

This might need to be adjusted to meet your needs, but it should at least show you how to do it.

Comment: I have an error in your first line The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ModelMap

Answer (score 0):

put each row contents in a map

```
   for(Row row :rows){
     HashMap map = new HashMap();
     map.put("id",row.getId());
     map.put("name",row.getName());
     jsonObj.append("rows", map);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a JSON tool like Google's GSON: http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/